# Hive select result was split

Tags: select, hive

I have a hive table whose files is string and the values is long string which contain some special character, such as space,'\' and so on as below.

I am trying to query the fields using below HQL.

select request from ops_lb where dt=140715 and request regexp '^GET /updateUserBilling.*username=zxzx_456.*' limit 100;

and it return some string as below, it seems that the **column was split into three lines**.[image]

How that happen? The max line number is 186.

Here is the updated HQL I am using:

select '000',request, '1111',http_user_agent,'222' from ops_lb where dt=140715 and request regexp '^GET /updateUserBilling.*username=zxzx_456.*' and host='api.usergrowth.pptv.com' limit 10;

And the output is:

**000     GET** /updateUserBilling?from=clt&format=json&data=1&username=zxzx_456&act=SHARE_VIDEO&version=3.5.2.0098&token=LVbR6iltJqvdBfbQFHDSbNXc22iPkMG9BGQ/RmGImcbpaTMFdgpcUfmSGXuWMRkv0gtd5g7oRsYc      NULL    NULL      NULL

ICFVjr0RLNL1B+R59SshdPg7393inG1gHQGyx9sUHmNIymiE4U9nad0OHq3Lgzv8enbX8cKVsO1e    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

DpA80xALDxgOdfIMaRk=&index=05&addstr=f13a2cf4c2cb6e12b96588dcfefa3cc8 HTTP/1.1  1111    Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) 222     NULL

**000     GET** /updateUserBilling?from=clt&format=json&data=1&username=zxzx_456&act=SHARE_VIDEO&version=3.5.2.0098&token=LVbR6iltJqvdBfbQFHDSbNXc22iPkMG9BGQ/RmGImcbpaTMFdgpcUfmSGXuWMRkv0gtd5g7oRsYc      NULL    NULL      NULL
ICFVjr0RLNL1B+R59SshdPg7393inG1gHQGyx9sUHmNIymiE4U9nad0OHq3Lgzv8enbX8cKVsO1e    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
DpA80xALDxgOdfIMaRk=&index=08&addstr=695d398d8b4939459da17fd77f7c687a HTTP/1.1  1111    Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) 222     NULL

**000     GET** /updateUserBilling?from=clt&format=json&data=1&username=zxzx_456&act=SHARE_VIDEO&version=3.5.2.0098&token=LVbR6iltJqvdBfbQFHDSbNXc22iPkMG9BGQ/RmGImcbpaTMFdgpcUfmSGXuWMRkv0gtd5g7oRsYc      NULL    NULL      NULL

ICFVjr0RLNL1B+R59SshdPg7393inG1gHQGyx9sUHmNIymiE4U9nad0OHq3Lgzv8enbX8cKVsO1e    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

DpA80xALDxgOdfIMaRk=&index=09&addstr=2968f55e6ac266c838d046c01a35a007 HTTP/1.1  1111    Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) 222     NULL

**000     GET** /updateUserBilling?from=clt&format=json&data=1&username=zxzx_456&act=STORE_VIDEO&version=3.5.2.0098&token=LVbR6iltJqvdBfbQFHDSbNXc22iPkMG9BGQ/RmGImcbpaTMFdgpcUfmSGXuWMRkv0gtd5g7oRsYc      NULL    NULL      NULL

Comment: Could you please format your code and post a text result instead of an image ? Right now, I'm affraid it is impossible to use the image you provided.

Comment: Also please give the table schema and a snippet of data you have inserted(2-3 lines will be ok).
Just a guess **^** symbol you need to escape with  "\\"

Comment: Thank you. I have add more content, please take a look.